# Type of QR code is used in envirologix QuickScan?

Tags: qr-code

This is a photo of the [QuickComb for QuickScan product made by envirologix](https://www.envirologix.com/catalog/quickcomb-kit-for-quickscan-corn-bulk-grain/).

Does anyone recognize the type of "QR code"/"fiducial marker"/barcode that it contains?

[image]

Comment: Probably proprietary, doesn't look like [one of the many included here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode)

Comment: Thanks! The closest I see on that page would be the "stacked barcode" aka Codablock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codablock ; but in this case the width seems to be equal the height; I would see 19 stacked 1D barcodes